# Comparing 2D arrays and returning booleans

Tags: java

I'm making a tile game, and at the end, I'm using the method `isGameOver()` to check that each tile in the 2D array `tiles` is in the right location (i.e. if it matches up `winningTiles`, where the elements are listed in order from 1-15)), and then return a boolean based on whether or not they match. All the user has to really do is enter 15 to make `tiles` match `winningTiles`, but `isGameOver()` won't return true and print the "you won!" statement regardless. Any idea what's wrong with my 2D array comparison?

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TileGame 
{
    public TileGame()
    {
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard(); 
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tileNumber = 0;     //User-entered tile number

        while (tileNumber != -1)
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter tile number: ");
            tileNumber = user_input.nextInt();

            if (tileNumber < 0)     //So user can enter -1 to quit the game
                System.exit(0);

            Point2D point = gameBoard.getTilePosition(tileNumber);  
            if (gameBoard.isEmptySpotANeighborOfTile(tileNumber, point))
                gameBoard.moveTile(tileNumber, point);
            if (gameBoard.isGameOver())
            {
                System.out.print("\nYou won!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new TileGame();
    }
}

class GameBoard
{
    int maxRows = 6;   
    int [][] tiles = { {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
                       {-1,  1,  2,  3,  4, -1},
                       {-1, 5, 6, 7, 8, -1},
                       {-1, 9, 10, 11, 12, -1},
                       {-1, 13, 14, 0, 15, -1},     
                       {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1} };

    public GameBoard()
    {
        printGameBoard();
    }

    public void printGameBoard()  //Prints current location of tiles to terminal window
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (maxRows - 1); i++)   
        {
           for(int j = 1; j < (maxRows - 1); j++)
           {
              System.out.printf("%5s ", tiles[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public Point2D getTilePosition(int tileNumber)  //Tells us where tile is currently located on the board
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (maxRows -1); i++)
        {
           for(int j = 1; j < (maxRows - 1); j++)
           {
               if(tileNumber == tiles[i][j])
               {
                    System.out.print("Tile number: " + tileNumber + "   Row: " + i + "   Column: " + j); 
                    Point2D.Double searchedTile = new Point2D.Double(i,j);  //Stores tile's location in Point2D object
                    return searchedTile;
               }
           }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public boolean isEmptySpotANeighborOfTile(int tileNumber, Point2D point) //Checks if empty spot(0) is neighboring the tile
    {
        int i = (int)point.getX();
        int j = (int)point.getY();

        if(tiles[i -1][j] == 0) 
        {
            System.out.print("\nEmpty spot as neighbor?: true");
            return true;
        }
        else if(tiles[i + 1][j] == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("\nEmpty spot as neighbor?: true");
            return true;
        }
        else if(tiles[i][j - 1] == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("\nEmpty spot as neighbor?: true");
            return true;
        }
        else if(tiles[i][j + 1] == 0) 
        {
            System.out.print("\nEmpty spot as neighbor?: true");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("\nEmpty spot as neighbor?: false");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void moveTile(int tileNumber, Point2D point)    //Switches empty spot and tile locations on the board
    {
        int i = (int)point.getX();
        int j = (int)point.getY();

        if(tiles[i -1][j] == 0)     
            tiles[i][j] = 0;
        else if(tiles[i + 1][j] == 0)
            tiles[i][j] = 0;
        else if(tiles[i][j - 1] == 0)
            tiles[i][j] = 0;
        else if(tiles[i][j + 1] == 0) 
            tiles[i][j] = 0;
    }

    public boolean isGameOver()     //Checks if each tile's in the right location & prints if the user has won
    {
        int[][] winningTiles = { {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},    
                                 {-1,  1,  2,  3,  4, -1},
                                 {-1, 5, 6, 7, 8, -1},
                                 {-1, 9, 10, 11, 12, -1},
                                 {-1, 13, 14, 15, 0, -1},     
                                 {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1} };

        for(int i = 1; i < tiles.length; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 1; j < tiles.length; j++)
           {
               if (tiles == winningTiles)
                   return true;
           }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your comparison should probably be `tiles[i][j] == winningTiles[i][j]` as it is it's checking if they're the same array, not if they have the same elements. In the future. You don't always need to include *all* of the code, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(tiles == winningTiles)
```

checks whether `tiles` and `winningTiles` refer to the same array, which they don't. To check a single element (say the one at `i`,`j`), use

```
if(tiles[i][j] == winningTiles[i][j])
```

This is not the only problem with your code, but this is the reason that `isGameOver` always returns false.

Comment: I've tried using this method and using deepEquals, and that just makes isGameOver() return true regardless of whether the game is won or not

Comment: @drjacobs That is because of another problem in the same code. You might be able to figure out what the problem is by running the program yourself with a pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you compare `if (tiles == winningTiles)`??? 
Its compare the reference or address of the object. You have to check each element by element of array.

You may use index number (e.g. using i and j) like `if (tiles[i][j] == winningTiles[j][j])`

or

You can use `Arrays.deepEquals(arr1, arr2)` method. So that you don't have to think about looping.

instead of below code just use `Arrays.deepEquals(tiles, winningTiles)`

```
for(int i = 1; i < tiles.length; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 1; j < tiles.length; j++)
           {
               if (tiles == winningTiles)
                   return true;
           }
        }
```